# Update problems in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I want update my table with two conditions :

```
Type == "پیش ثبت نام" && Approved == false
```

and I use this code :

```
using (NoavaranModel.NoavaranEntities1 db=new NoavaranModel.NoavaranEntities1())
{
    var query = db.Students.Where(p => p.Type == "پیش ثبت نام" && p.Approved == false).Single();
    query.IsRecivedSMS = true;

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

but it's not working. Just updates one recode in db. How can I update all rows with above conditions in Entity Framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the query to not select only one record which fits your contition, but all. Then update them all.

```
using (NoavaranModel.NoavaranEntities1 db=new NoavaranModel.NoavaranEntities1())
        {
            var query = db.Students.Where(p => p.Type == "پیش ثبت نام" && p.Approved == false);
            foreach(var record in query)
            {
              record.IsRecivedSMS = true;
            }

            db.SaveChanges();

        }
```

Comment: does not contain a definition for 'ForEach'

Comment: ah sorry, was too quick with the fingers ;-)
see updated answer